# IPhone SDK: Adding a UIActivityIndicatorView to a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Why doesn't the cell show anything in this code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
cell.textLabel.text=@"Carregando...";
[spinner release];
```

I'm doing this inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I tried size to fit, create a frame to `cell.imageView` and a same size frame to the spinner, but nothing works.

What´s wrong with this code?

Thank you..!

Comment: Are you setting the frame of the activity indicator?  Something like spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)?  You could also check the frame and visibility of the cell.imageView itself.

Comment: Yes, I created both, the spinner frame and setup his visibility... But I found the answer as I described bellow... Thanks for the help..!

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer...

David Maymudes was partialy right... It´s necessary to have a "background" to the cell.imageView... But must be a image, not just a frame. So just create a UIImage as a "white background" and set in cell.imageView.image. The code will be:

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 UIImage *whiteback = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"whiteback.png"];
 cell.imageView.image = whiteback;
 [cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
 [spinner startAnimating];
 cell.textLabel.text=@"Carregando...";
 [whiteback release];
 [spinner release];
```

The whiteback.png is just a 25x25 pixels white square...

Thanks for everyone help... See you...

Answer (score 9):

A slight modification of the method from Thiago:

I think adding the spinner directly to the cell view felt a little hacky, so I used a 1x1 transparent png as the image view and resized it to be whatever my spinner size is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"NoReuse"] autorelease];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];

// Spacer is a 1x1 transparent png
UIImage *spacer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spacer"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(spinner.frame.size);

[spacer drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,spinner.frame.size.width,spinner.frame.size.height)];
UIImage* resizedSpacer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
cell.imageView.image = resizedSpacer;
[cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];

return cell;
```

That gives a cell that looks like this:

[image: loading cell]

Answer (score 3):

I think the cell's imageView will probably have a zero-size rectangle, because you haven't put a picture in it.  So the spinner is inside but invisible.

So instead of putting the spinner within the imageView, just put it within the cell...

```
[cell addSubview:spinner];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(145, 0, 30, 30); // if you want it centered horizontally...
```

you could also do

```
cell.accessoryView = spinner;
```

to put the spinner over at the far right of the cell.

Comment: The acessoryView worked very well... But the spinner.frame doesn´t... I found a solution that is to create a "white square" UIImage and them put as cell.imageView.image... Them the spinner appears... But thanks for your help..!

Comment: sorry about that; I should have tested it myself rather than trusting the other commenter!