# The correct way to use UIActivityIndicatorView inside UITableView when pressing on a cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, user-interface

I have a few options:

1. Put it on the left, in the cell.imageView.
2. Put it on the right, in the cell.accesorryView
3. Put it on the tableView, over the table (looks really ugly)
4. Put it on the tableView, covering all the table with an overlayView

Which one is the correct way to do it? (Or do you have any other ideas?) I can't find any reference to this in Apple's Table view programming guide.

Comment: It depends on what the app will do when you press the cell. Could you provide any context?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269188/iphone-sdk-adding-a-uiactivityindicatorview-to-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: It'll basically do a loading on the background, then it might add some rows to the table if there's any new data. Does that kind of make sense?

Comment: @Jhaliya I looked at that question, but I'm not sure what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @the_great_monkey : you should go with your second choice ... "Put it on the right, in the cell.accesorryView" .

Comment: Jhaliya is right. It is pretty much the context that should help you make your choice. Since the event is cell related, you must indicate it within the cell. That eliminates 3 & 4. `cell.accessoryView` has been a common choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't indicate whether you want to block all access to the app while the operation is performing or whether you just want to disable the tableView.  Here is what I have done in the past when I want to block all access to the app:

1. Disable the application view.
2. Add a new view on top with a black background, but with perhaps .6 alpha.  Make it perhaps 150x150 with rounded corners.
3. Add the UIActivityIndicatorView to the black view in the horizontal center, but a little higher than the vertical center.
4. Add a label for some status text to inform the user what is going on.
5. When the background task is completed, remove the view and re-enable the application view.

It makes for a nicely polished "wait" for the user.

EDIT:  Here is the code that I use to disable the application while the process is running in the background:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) {
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}

[window setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

---

**Added from OP's suggested edit:**

If for some reason the above technique doesn't work, the other workarounds are:

1. Calling `setExclusiveTouch` on the view that you lay use to indicate it's loading
2. Calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringEvents]` and later calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringEvents]` when we finished.

Comment: So it's much like the Twitter's app isn't it? I think I should be able to do that, but what do you mean by disable application view? Just add a subview on the top, right?

Comment: I haven't seen the Twitter app, but there are a lot of apps that use that method.  I actually disable the entire user interface so that the user doesn't take any further action while the process is running.  Then I add the subview on top.  When the process is done, I remove the subview and then enable the interaction again.  I'll update my answer above.

Comment: You're a champion. Thanks for the answer. Great help. BTW is there any reason to assume that the first object at uiapplication windows has to be the active window?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I read somewhere that Index 0 is always the window on top and hence the active window.

Comment: Thanks very much, that really helps. I have one more question: How come this technique (of disabling window) doesn't work for a tabbar application? I have one tabbar that has a table view inside, but that code doesn't seem to be blocking the user inputs (it worked on a table view alone without tab bar)

Comment: Hmm... my app is also a tabbar application and it worked for me.  Is the tabbar your root controller?  That should be index 0.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with my application, but I found two other ways to do this: by calling setExclusiveTouch on the overlay view or by calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringEvents] and later calling endIgnoringEvents. The first method doesn't seem to work for me, but the second one does. I actually want to investigate a bit more on those issues, but I'm running out of time. So I'll perhaps leave that mystery for later.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not moving into another view, sounds like you could either put it as an accessory view, or, if you have a navigation bar, put it in there.

I wouldn't put it on the imageView on any situation, since that image view is more for an image related specifically to the cell's content.

Comment: I might be leaving one more important detail. I don't want the user to press on any other cell until I finish, does this change your answer?